# waterline and mysql without sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am building a node app and want to use waterline and mysql without sails. I cannot get the adapter to work. The exact error I get with the code from below is:

`C:\node\mlb\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\core\index.js:70
var schemaAttributes = this.waterline.schema[this.identity].attributes;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined`

Here is my code:

```
var Waterline = require('waterline');
var mysql = require('sails-mysql');

mysql.config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mlb',
  port: '3306',
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'xxxxxxxx'
}

var Batter = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  adapter: 'mysql',
  attributes: {
    name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
   }
 }
});

new Batter({ tableName: 'batters', adapters: { mysql: mysql }}, function (err, Model) {
    Model.findAll().exec(function(err, batters) {
    // Now we have an array of users
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the official [waterline examples](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/tree/master/example/raw)? There are several things you are missing, for example, you need to instantiate and initialise waterline before you can do any CRUD operations.

Comment: I did not see those examples. I will play around with my code.

Comment: Any chance you could show me a bare bones raw config. I'm having a real hard time getting it to work.

Comment: It doesn't get much rawer than that waterline example... What was the issue you had with it?

Comment: I'll update my OP with the new code in about an hour. Thanks for looking it this.